# Scenebuilder - Where do I find it?

Tags: javafx

I've recently started to delve into JavaFX and what it can offer me, however a fairly critical part of the technology seems to be scenebuilder, which I can't seem to find. It used to be listed on the Oracle website, but it seems that SceneBuilder is now included in JDK8. However, I cannot seem to find it!
I'm on Mac, have I misunderstood something? Or am I simply being an idiot?

Comment: You can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SceneBuilder is not included with JDK version 8.0.0 or 8.0.5. From the [JDK download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), scroll down to "Additional Resources" and you will find the link to download it there.

Comment: It seems I had misunderstood then!

Answer (score 0):

SceneBuilder is now available by Gluon:

http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

Oracle still looks as if it where offering it but if you read the fine print 
their support is somewhat "limited":

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html